# How to access Identity methods without creating managers

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use some functionalities from UserManager, like :

```
GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync, ValidateTokenAsync and GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync
```

But I am not using Identity structure. I created my own database and User manager.

Is that possible to access those methods in that way? Maybe with a thin UserManager implementation ?
Or should I develope all that methods by my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Identity source being available on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity), why not check out the [methods](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/0ef83207d4a6337cf5eecbd5165721b806713ee2/src/Core/UserManager.cs#L891) you [need](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/0ef83207d4a6337cf5eecbd5165721b806713ee2/src/Core/UserManager.cs#L1456) and [implement](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/0ef83207d4a6337cf5eecbd5165721b806713ee2/src/Core/UserManager.cs#L1691) them best way it fits your architecture?